# UIImageView fit to View frame size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiimageview, autolayout

When I create a new ViewController and I drag a UIImageView to this, the UIIV grows to fit fullscreen with the width and height from the screen. If I change between 4 and 3,5" screen, the UIImageView changes his height dynamically.

[image]

BUT, when I try to insert an UIImageView to a view with more elements, this UIImageView is setted with 4:3 ratio size, and if I try to resize this to fullscreen, when I change between screen sizes, a part of the imageView is hidden.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to illustrate with those screenshots. Other than you have auto layout conflicts, this may be causing your issue.

Comment: Yes...screenchots are bad, i'm goig to update them!

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: use Auto layout

---

Long Answer:

1. select imageview, add **left**, **right**, **top**, **bottom** constraints (all equal to 0) to tableview
2. select imageview, update frames

---

[image: step 1]

---

[image: step 2]

Comment: Hey @oldman, when I make the Update Frames, the UIImageView is super sized and I can see only the top left corner of the picture...any ideas? And i haven't got a TableView, it's a simple View, thanks!!!

Comment: @pekpon I guess you should set constraints for **height** and **width** to the UIImageView

Comment: but if I set the height for 4 inches screen, when I try this in iphone 4 with 3,5 inch screen, the uiimageview is cuted!